# Как в Visual Studio убрать Developer News со стартовой страницы?

Tags: visual-studio

Можно ли как-то заблокировать панель Developer News на стартовой странице Visual Studio (которая открывается через File - Start Page)?

Пробовал найти какие-то элементы управления этой страницей на ней самой, плюс [перебирал варианты](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7201260/5752652) в Options -> Environment -> Startup, ничего нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов два: сложный и простой.

Сложный вариант представляет собой создание собственной стартовой страницы и установку её (через Tools -> Extension and Updates) в студию. Плюсы – полная кастомизация, минусы – достаточно долго. Входная точка для тех, кто хочет этим заниматься – [Customizing the Start Page for Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa991992.aspx).

Простой вариант подразумевает установку уже готовых стартовых страниц, там же в Tools -> Extension and Updates.

Например, можно установить Solution Start Page от Herdo и поставить её в настройках стартовой страницы.